# A sequence of functions that converges pointwise on $(0, 1)$ but not uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am having trouble understanding why the sequence of functions defined by
$$ f_n(x) = \min(1-\frac{1}{n}, x)$$ on $(0, 1)$ does satisfy the condition of pointwise but not uniform convergence on $(0, 1)$.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Got the question wrong on the midterm and feeling sad at this moment.

Comment: Did you figure out the limit?

Comment: Your sequence converges uniformly to the function $f_\infty(x) = x$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, if $n > 1/\epsilon$ then $|f_n(x) - f_\infty(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: I see. I should try harder next time.

Comment: Don't feel too glum, chum. This kind of thing happens, and the best thing to do is understand what went wrong and learn from that (which it appears you are doing).